# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
I don't know how to do. I have a pic where vs tel me where it't the problem.

[image: photo link]

```
`---------------------Controller

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using AppTest.Models;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using AppTest.ViewModels;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data.Entity;


    namespace AppTest.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDbContext _context;
            public HomeController()
            {
                _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            }
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
            public ViewResult Index()
            {
                var saloane = _context.Saloane.Include(c => c.Id).ToList();
                return View(saloane);
            }
            public ActionResult Details (int id)
            {
                var salon = _context.Saloane.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
                if (salon == null)
                    return HttpNotFound();
                return View(salon);

            }


    --------------------------------Index
    @model IEnumerable<AppTest.Models.Salon>


    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Saloane</h2>
    @if (1>1)
    {
        <p>We don't have any customers yet.</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Saloane</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var salon in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(salon.Nume,"Adresa", "Id_Oras",new { id = salon.Id }, null)</td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    `
```

Comment: `Include` is meant for navigation properties `Id` is just a regular property.

Comment: The exception message is self explanatory. `Include(c => c.Id)` is not valid, just remove it.

Comment: i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Ivan-stoev, you're using `.Include()` when you dont need to.

`.Include()` is used to include linked navigation properties (related entities) in the same database transaction - you just need to return a list.

Try

`var saloane = _context.Saloane.ToList();`

or, if you want to filter your list, use:

`var saloane = _context.Saloane.Where(c => c.SomeProperty == "something").ToList();`

Comment: I used var saloane = _context.Saloane.ToList(); and the same problem.

Comment: If you have changed the code, then it is impossible to get the same error because the old error was specifically because you were using `.Include(c=>c.Id)` - if you upload your new error to imgur and add the link as a comment I'll try to help.

Comment: That error means that your database does not match your entity model (your code). You probably need to run migrations or update your data model depending on if you're doing code first or database first. Your original issue is now resolved, so you should close this issue and create a new one if you can't manage to fix that yourself (but Google is your friend-use it!)